# Is the way wizard duel in Harry Potter based on fencing?

Tags: harry-potter, inspiration

As in how they (like fencing) put their wand up to their face before they duel and how they have their stance.

[image: two fencers in a duel]
[image: two wizards in a duel]

Comment: In the film they also do the swishy salute that fencers do; https://sites.google.com/site/msholtslatinsite/_/rsrc/1377726565455/mandatoryhandouts7th/harry-potter-latin-game/wizards%27duel.jpg

Comment: The word 'duel' itself is very closely connected with fencing in the historical context and associated fiction (The Three Musketeers, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it is. In the duelling club in CoS Gilderoy Lockhart's outfit and stance look exactly like a (olschool) fencer:

[image: Gilderoy Lockhart]